# Very much offset (mkchromecast)

Tags: sound, google

I downloaded and installed mkchromecast to cast my desktop audio to my google home mini. Everything works fine, but if I hit play on my computer, it needs about 30 seconds till the audio is played on my google home. I already tried to make it better by choosing different bitrates and sample rates, but it doesn't really work.
Thanks for your help!